# Problem after flashing Sony Xperia Mini

Tags: rom-flashing

This is related to [How to root the Xperia Mini ST15i](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25065/how-to-root-the-xperia-mini-st15i/32141#32141).

I followed the instructions from the answer, but I'm stuck.

> Now open the flashtool again and flash the stock kernel of ST15i and
>   now enjoy the rooted phone. For check if you have rooted your phone
>   successful there is an app installed superuser on your phone or you
>   can download the Go backup/Titanium Backup to check out its rooted or
>   not.

After flashing the stock kernel, the phone is stuck with the Sony logo, and keeps on restarting. The phone can't detected by the PC, the Sony PC companion, or the Sony Ericsson Update Service. Because it can't be detected, I can't flash it. It doesn't even charge when it's connected through the charger cable.

Comment: Phone getting stuck to on the boot animation and restarting it again and again is probably a sign of kernel and ROM mismatch. Verify this.

Comment: what is to be done in my case to access the phone ?

Comment: Instead of simply referring to another question, can you mention here all that you have done? That will be easier to understand and to help you better.

Comment: Yes, so as I said it's a ROM - Kernel mismatch problem. You were running a newer ROM version and flashed another kernel which doesn't work with your ROM. Now the solution would be that you find the kernel for the ROM that you were running. Hope I am understanding your problem correctly.

Comment: Formerly i had android 4.1.B.0.587 version running on my phone. i thought of rooting my phone and i came to know that firstly it had to be downgraded.
So, i used flashtool and flashed ST15i_4.0.2.A.0.62 which was successful.
Then, for rooting I used DoomLord root toolkit. AFter this was successful, i proceeded with flashing the stock kernel of ST15i. the process wasn't successful as the phone continuously restarted.

Now, the phone isn't detected by the pc and can't even be charged. So, i can't do anything with my phone as it continuously restarts on the sony logo

Answer (score 0):

Same problem was with me I have tried flashing by flashtool by switching off my sony ST15i and then connecting to the PC by data cable and pressing vol+ key at the same time. Your phone will glow a green light it means your phone is in flashing mode. It was sucessfull, I have tried it many times it always work.But after a month it shows no servis or emergency call I don't know what to do with it but my phone works properly but remember use only Ginger Bird ROM otherwise it may be wouldn't work.