# ROOTING THE ANDROID DEVICE

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rooting

Hope y'all doing fine, My question may be so lame sorry but wanted to know the answer.. how to root a android device I have mobile of Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini (ST15i) I bought that before 3 years, still use the thing it's still good working condition but on the latest update of the software which it sucked all my internal memory now i have only 100 MB to usable and latest update of Facebook alone is 25 MB + extra data 30 + cache 10 MB and total is 65 MB (rough calculation) so thought of removing the unwanted default apps which came with the update which were uninstallable searched for removing, [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/)  said that the best bid is to root our device and so can you guys please guide me how to root I checked with SuperOneClick it never worked

Answer (score 0):

So, here I will be trying to help you real fast by directly dropping you over to the thread over stack exchange [How to root the Xperia Mini ST15i](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25065/how-to-root-the-xperia-mini-st15i).

PS: Updated the link.

Comment: bro downloadable files which has root tool kit have been removed.. :(

Comment: Oops I think I may have to check it before giving it to you ! @rajesh now try looking over the post I have updated the post.